# How to clear Hadoop jobs history

Tags: hadoop

I'm using Hadoop Map/Reduce Administration UI coming with standard Apache distro. With the time the list of executed jobs is growing too big. How I can remove old jobs from the history list?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop job execution has life cycle, which is explained 
[here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/hadoop-log-location-and-retention/)

Job status flow 
Running -> Completed -> Retired

There are important configurations using which we can control the job retention.

```
mapred.jobtracker.completeuserjobs.maximum: Number of jobs to keep in memory after Running state. Try configure to less value...

mapred.jobtracker.retirejob.interval: Default interval value is  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (1 Day). That means completed jobs will be retired after one day by default.
```

Try configuring property "mapred.jobtracker.retirejob.interval" to 1 hour or so.

Comment: These are parameters from older versions of Hadoop and do not work with the current version. The closest parameter for doing it might be `mapreduce.jobhistory.joblist.cache.size`.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion (more extreme) is just to restart your jobtracker.